# If $f(t) = 1+ \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+....+\frac{1}{t}$, find $\sum^n_{r=1} (2r+1)f(r)$ in terms of $f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $f(t) = 1+ \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+....+\frac{1}{t}$,

Find $x$ and $y$ such that $\sum^n_{r=1} (2r+1)f(r) =xf(r) -y$

Comment: Firstly, $f()$ isn't a polynomial; it's not even a rational function of $t$, since its denominator grows faster than any power of $t$ does (it's $LCM(1\ldots t)$, which grows similarly to $t!$).  Secondly, it's not entirely clear what's being asked; are you supposed to find $x$ and $y$ in the given expression?

Comment: I think  $LCM(1…t) \approx e^t$ (from the prime number theorem).

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I presume the actual problem is.  Sultan, if this is wrong, please let me know and feel free to further edit to express the real question.

Comment: $xf(r) -y$ or $xf(n) -y$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming that the problem asks you to find $x$ and $y$ to make the stated equation true.  If that's so, then you should be able to use the concept of [*summation by parts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) (which is the discrete equivalent of integration by parts) to solve the problem; choosing $f_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i$ and $\Delta g_k=2k+1$, then you should be able to find simple closed forms both for $\Delta f_k$ and for the $g_k$ (hint: $g_{k+1} = \Delta g_k+g_k = g_k+(2k+1)$ ) and thus use the summation by parts formula to express your sum in terms of $f(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1$, we'd expect $\sum_{r=1}^n (2r+1)f(r)$ to be something like $n^2 f(n)$. A little experimentation shows that it's actually $(n+1)^2 f(n) - n(n+1)/2$. $\textbf{Proof}$: At $n=1$, this is $4 - 1 = 3 = (2+1)f(1)$. 
The forward difference of $(n+1)^2 f(n) - n(n+1)/2$ is $(n+2)^2 f(n+1) - (n+1)(n+2)/2 - [(n+1)^2 f(n) - n(n+1)/2] 
= (n+2)^2 f(n+1) - (n+1)^2 (f(n+1)-1/(n+1)) - (n+1) 
= (2n+3)f(n+1) = (2(n+1)+1)f(n+1)$,
as required.